# Is a template class compiled more than once in different compilation units in C++?

Tags: c++, templates

Let's say I have the following code:

```
// templateClass.h
#ifndef TEMPLATE_CLASS_H
#define TEMPLATE_CLASS_H

template <typename T>
class tClass
{
public:
  tClass();
};

#endif

// templateClassDef.inl
#ifndef TEMPLATE_CLASS_DEF_INL
#define TEMPLATE_CLASS_DEF_INL

template <typename T>
tClass<T>::tClass()
{
}

#endif

// normalClass.h
#include "templateClass.h"

class normal
{
public:
  normal();
};

// normalClass.cpp
#include "normalClass.h"
#include "templateClassDef.inl"

normal::normal()
{
  tClass<int> a;
}

// main.cpp
#include "templateClass.h"
#include "templateClassDef.inl"

#include "normalClass.h"

int main()
{
  tClass<int> a;
  normal b;

  return 0;
}
```

Note that the `inl` file is NOT being included in the header as it normally is, but is instead included in the source files (I am aware that is not the standard way... this is just an example). Notice that `normalcClass.cpp` is instantiating `tClass<int>` and so is `main.cpp`.

I am curious as to whether the compiler has to construct the instantiation from the template class every time it encounters an explicit instantiation, considering it is the same type (i.e. `tClass<int>`) *even though* both instantiations occur in separate translation units (`normalClass.cpp` and `main.cpp`)? Also, will this increase in compile time (If the answer to the previous question is *yes it will instantiate it again* then this should also be *yes*)?

Comment: this is compiler dependant, but the answer is yes to both questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, yes, template classes are usually compiled every time they're encountered by the compiler.

Comment: Why doesn't the compiler 'store' the new class somewhere and when it encounters it, it uses the already compiled class rather than compile a new one? And why doesn't it error out by saying something like _same class name and definition_ if it does create the new type multiple times?

Comment: @Samaursa: Don't quote me on this, but I think some compilers do in fact "cache" template instantiations in order to support advanced [template metaprogramming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming) techniques. However I think compilers will check anyway to diagnose violations of the one definition rule.

Comment: The linker will remove all but one copy of each instantiation.  But the compiler can't know what other modules you will link with, so it has to compile whatever instantiations you use, unless you provide a promise to provide it at link time, using `extern`.  Templates, like inline functions, are exempted from the multiple definitions conflict; the linker will just pick one copy to use.  The ODR rule still applies, all copies with the same name must have identical behavior, so that which one the linker picks doesn't matter.

Comment: @Samaursa: the problem is essentially this "somewhere"!  Iit needs to be up to date with the latest changes in the system. Having an extra unit of instantiations which is essentially used by anything somehow build but not really associated with any component is a maintenance nightmare. It may work OK with tinybprojects of a couple if hundred translation units but efficiently building a suite of projects sharing tens of thousands translation units already is a nightmare without this!

Answer (score 4):

Basically, templates are instantiated per compile unit, which increases compile time. There are some extensions and features in the new C++ standard to handle this issue, like explicit instantiation and externalization. See this doc for some explanations and optimization techniques:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Template-Instantiation.html

Comment: They're *compiled* for every compilation unit and for every set of template arguments, which increases compile time.  And instantiations for different arguments can bloat the binary.  But I've never heard of the same instantiation appearing in the binary multiple times due to multiple compilation units.

Comment: Yes, signatures would collide otherwise. I wanted to point out, that the compiler itself cannot know which instantiation really is used and therefore, all instances were created/referenced per compile unit. I recently had problems with a shared library, which was too big. Static linking did it for me.

Comment: But the "bloat your binary" part is misleading.

Answer (score 2):

How the compiler implements the template instantiation mechanism is up to the compiler. Practically, the needed and visible function template definitions are created when it is used in a translation unit. This can create quite a bit of unnecessary work. For example, every time you use IOstreams in a translation unit all the correspondung functions from the stream and locale classes are instantiated. ... always with the same two types!

Depending on what the template is for it may be viable to put the implementation into a source file rather than into a header and explicitly instantiate the template in the source. When there are lots of different instantiations being used this isn't viable. In this case it may be reasonable to to predefine commonly use instantiations. For this you can declare instantiations to be extern in C++2011. Of course, you then need to explicitly instantiate the corresponding functions or classes somewhere.

Comment: Sadly (or not so much), even “extern” went away and underlying issue with templates is not resolved in 2019.. having some luck pulling specific method declarations out of the “impl” header and adding to specific “trait impl” headers that are externally exercised (and only included) in a forward compiled TU linked in. However, this is a manual process and can result in needless instantiations if said “trait methods” are never used. Also requires control over initial source and separated definitions of types participating in instantiations. So much grief for something so core to many C++ usages.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, compilation units are compiled independently from each other.

However, many toolchains support pre-compiled headers which circumvent this, and allow the compiler to reuse already processed code in another compilation unit.

Comment: PCH doesn’t appear to address instantiations and re-use of such. In the code I am working on this dominates any parsing time (or PCH) mitigation. Having a cache of “compiled template” objects (eg. hash on related input state and names, assuming that such implies ODR is not violated) such that the actual instantiations could be re-used would significantly increase the overall (initial) compilation speed.. separate issue from PCH and the parsing doesn’t appear to the bottleneck. This could also apply to repeated instantiations (not parsing) of core STL. Parsing would be a separate cache layer.

Comment: @user2864740: PCH addresses everything up to the point of the end of the header designated for PCH control (named on the command-line in the `/Yu` option).  PCH is implemented by freezing and persisting the whole compiler state... not just the parser output.

Comment: (The above comment may not apply to PCH-equivalent features in compilers other than Visual C++)

Comment: If the control happens before the template instantiations then.. back to the issue of not covering multiple (repetitive) instantiations across TUs. If after then can get same effect with forced instantiation in a TU and undefined symbol definitions (or extern if that's your roll). At least in Clang (nice to see now with --ftime-trace), it's the instantiations that are a bottle.. granted that's also a problem with the code design in general, given that they can take up to 20 seconds PER top-level instantiation.

Comment: I guess, as an implementation detail, seems like there could be: `c++ whatever.cc --instantiation-cache=cache.o.impl` as an augment to any other parsing concern (not currently anything similar in GCC or Clang).

Comment: "If the control happens before the template instantiations"  But that's completely your choice as the programmer.  You didn't get them precompiled **because** you didn't put them in the header used to build the PCH.